# Android, storing several MB of app data safely (security/error free) and considerately (not filling storage)?

Tags: android, security, storage, space

My Android application is heavily image intensive. Out of consideration for the multiple phone specifications, my application optimizes all the images to smaller, easier to handle sizes for the devices that require them.

At present these are stored in:

```
/data/data/com.myapp.example/files
```

However I feel there are two important considerations to make,

First of all that the application will take up approximately 10MB of additional space after the initial "setup". How can I make this as small a problem as possible for the user? I havn't considered outputting them to the SD card because they are licensed material and SD is totally insecure. (although i'm totally aware that so is data directory from rooted devices). What would be the solution to this problem?

My second consideration is that I need to be able to know if there is enough space on the users device before I start trying to use it, is there some way I can find out before I begin the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not saving the files on the SDCard and encrypt them using some strong algorithm? As you say, /data is as secure as the SDCard ...

To check available space for a given path, use the [StatFs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html) class.

---

Edit 11/04/2011:

you should make some tests to check whether decrypting the data will be too slow or not. You might have a good surprise. Also check out [TEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm) and [Blowfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29) algorithms which seem to be amongst the fastest "strong" algorithms. Or simply encrypt your data using a very simple algorithm of your own which will prevent direct ripping of the images (but not resist to better hackers).

And I don't think there will be any secure area on the phone where to temporarly store decrypted files because any root user can access any place of the phone (and rooting an android is very simple for anyone)

---

Edit 12/04/2011:

Do you need all 10MB at once? Isn't loading stuff in memory possible? Is your application crashing with OutOfMemoryException if you load your data on application startup (and/or in the background) and keep it loaded during the life time of the application?

One last possibility would be to decrypt/load stuff in memory using some native interface : memory is allocated outside the Java heap which would not eat the application memory quota and decoding would be greatly speeded up as native code will run much faster than the equivalent Java code.

Comment: Thanks for the StatFs info. As for encrypting, I need to be able to load these images on the fly, very quickly, the problem with encryption is that it makes them resource intensive to decrypt. It there a semi-secure, temporary location I can decrypt them to at run-time?

Comment: This is a slight problem, you are correct on the problem of rooting, it's too simple, on the other hand, decrypting on the fly adds overhead which I can't afford to add into an app that is already pushing the limit on some of hte lower end devices.

Comment: Thanks, the 10MB are mostly images, I don't load them all at once, unfortunately, because they're images, just a couple of them loaded into memory (decompressed as Bitmaps) become very large and quickly exceed the memory limit. Is there an alternative way I can load them into memory without actually decoding them into bitmaps?

Comment: You can always read a whole file and put it in memory inside a ByteBuffer. Then when you want to read it, instead of using a FileInputStream, you would use the ByteBuffer containing the raw data.

Comment: That sounds like a plan. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. "As small as possible" - well, if you require 10MB of data, then you require 10MB of data. There's not much you can do to get it smaller, other than compressing the data. Of course, if not all of this data is required, you could consider splitting the data up into separate modules and either offer those on the market as plug-ins, or let the user choose which data is required on startup and then download it off your own server.
2. SD itself is insecure, but you can encrypt the data. Of course, nothing is foolproof, but a reasonable encryption algorithm will stop casual copying of the data.
3. Whatever you do, remember to enable the "install to SD" option in your app.

Comment: EboMike, you should check your quote for number 1, not only is it inaccurate but it's misinterpreted. I said "make this as small a problem as possible". The data is fixed, and the user needs it all, there is no making it smaller other than compression as you say and that is not desired. Can you suggest a method that would not be resource intensive for on-the-fly loading if i was to use option 2. And as for 3, don't worry, I'm an Android comsumer too, first thing I ensured was that it can be installed to SD.

Comment: Sorry about that, it was late :) But everything in there still stands - compress if possible, make modular if some users don't need all of it, encrypt and move to SD.